# make ld: Command not found in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nasm, ld

I am trying to create executable file though following code,

```
exe.x : obj.o
     ld -o exe.x obj.o
obj.o : a01.asm
     nasm -f win64 -o obj.o -l list.l a01.asm
```

When I run this file via "make" command in terminal it only gives object file and list file, then stop and shows make ld: Command not found and suggest "sudo apt install  ld", but this also gives me error "Unable to locate package ld" . I use latest version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

You have to install the package `binutils`.
It contains tools like an assembler (`gas`),the linker (`ld`) and other utilities like `objdump` to work with object/executable files.